# Referring to inner field objects in Elasticsearch with Grafana and Cloudfoundry

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud-foundry, grafana

I'm trying to get metrics from CloudFoundry via CF API and Elasticsearch emmitting to Grafana.
My problem is when I would like to create a variable in Grafana, I don't get any results.
Maybe I'm way off but this is what I tried.

I have a response like this format: https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/apps/get_detailed_stats_for_a_started_app.html

I'm trying to create a variable for the `app_name`, so I guess I'd need `0.stats.name`. Still [my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gvZw.png) don't give any results. What I miss with `{"find": "terms", "field": "0.stats.name"}`?

Comment: Do **not** pull metrics from Cloud Controller.  It doesn't scale.  You will end up needing a ton of Cloud Controllers or you'll end up DoS'ing yourself (or you'll hit your providers rate limit).  The proper way to get metrics from Cloud Foundry is through the firehose, https://github.com/cloudfoundry/loggregator#consuming-the-firehose.  The firehose lets you listen for metrics and is way more efficient.  This cf cli plugin helps to see what metrics are available with the firehose,  https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-plugin.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes that would be the way, if I had admin right on the whole Cloud Foundry. Since I'm only admin on my org, I couldn't find another solution.

Comment: You don't need admin access to get to the firehose.  You can consume for specific apps.  See the firehose-plugin to the cf cli's `app-nozzle` command.  That does not require admin access.

Comment: Thanks, that's cool. Though I cannot stop that command with timeout...it continuously emits data until I restart my PC :'D

Comment: Hitting `ctrl+c` should stop it, but I've only used it on Linux / MacOS.  I think Windows should be the same, but I don't use Windows so I can't say for sure.  I do know that for best compatibility, you should use the cf cli in the Windows Command Prompt and not in Cygwin / Git Bash shell.  The latter two have not always worked properly with the cf cli.